# assigning strtof value into 2D array in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to parse a CSV file into a 2D array in C. I want to make a matrix wit the structure :

```
typedef struct {
    int row;
    int col;
    float **arr;
    int numElements;
} Matrix;
```

The function I'm using takes in a dynamically allocated 2D array of floats, and is returned. I'm reading the values in using fgets, tokenizing each value between commas using strtok and then converting the string returned using strtof.

First, I made the 2D arrays dynamically and then pass them to the function to be filled in with values,

```
RMatrix->arr = make2DArray(RMatrix->row, RMatrix->col);
    VMatrix->arr = make2DArray(VMatrix->row, VMatrix->col);

    printf("RMatrix->arr : %p \n", RMatrix->arr);
    printf("VMatrix->arr : %p \n", VMatrix->arr);

    parseCSV(fpRMatrix, RMatrix->arr, RMatrix->row, RMatrix->col, &(RMatrix->numElements), INPUT_LENGTH);
    printf("RMatrix parsed\n");
    parseCSV(fpVMatrix, VMatrix->arr, VMatrix->row, VMatrix->col, &(VMatrix->numElements), INPUT_LENGTH);
    printf("VMatrix parsed\n");
```

Below are the functions :

```
void parseCSV(FILE *fp, float **output, int row, int col, int *numElements ,int inputLength)
{
    char *buffer;
    int rowArr = 0;

    printf("Output : %p \n", output);

    buffer = (char*) malloc(inputLength * sizeof(char));

    while(fgets(buffer, inputLength, fp)) {
        char *p =strtok(buffer,",");
        int colArr = 0;         
        float check = 0;

        while(p)
        {
            printf("p now : %s \n", p);
            check = strtof(p, (char**) NULL);
            printf("check now : %f \n", check);
            output[rowArr][colArr] = strtof(p, (char**) NULL);
            *numElements += 1;
            colArr++;
            p = strtok('\0',",");
            printf("output[%d][%d] : %f  ", rowArr, colArr, output[rowArr][colArr]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        rowArr++;
    }
    printf("numElements in the end : %d\n", *numElements);
    free(buffer);

}

float **make2DArray(int row, int col) 
{  
    float** arr;
    float* temp;

    arr = (float**)malloc(row * sizeof(float*));
    temp = (float*)malloc(row * col * sizeof(float));
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        arr[i] = temp + (i * row);
    }

    return arr;

}
```

The output :

```
Name : RMatrix
NumElements : 0
Rows : 2
Cols : 4
Name : VMatrix
NumElements : 0
Rows : 2
Cols : 4
RMatrix->arr : 0x11684d0 
VMatrix->arr : 0x1168520 
Output : 0x11684d0 
p now : 1 
check now : 1.000000 
output[0][1] : 0.000000  p now : 2 
check now : 2.000000 
output[0][2] : 0.000000  p now : 3 
check now : 3.000000 
output[0][3] : 0.000000  p now : 4

check now : 4.000000 
output[0][4] : 0.000000  
p now : 5 
check now : 5.000000 
output[1][1] : 4.000000  p now : 6 
check now : 6.000000 
output[1][2] : 0.000000  p now : 7 
check now : 7.000000 
output[1][3] : 0.000000  p now : 8

check now : 8.000000 
output[1][4] : 0.000000  
numElements in the end : 8
RMatrix parsed
Output : 0x1168520 
p now : 1 
check now : 1.000000 
output[0][1] : 0.000000  p now : 2 
check now : 2.000000 
output[0][2] : 0.000000  p now : 3 
check now : 3.000000 
output[0][3] : 0.000000  p now : 4

check now : 4.000000 
output[0][4] : 0.000000  
p now : 5 
check now : 5.000000 
output[1][1] : 4.000000  p now : 6 
check now : 6.000000 
output[1][2] : 0.000000  p now : 7 
check now : 7.000000 
output[1][3] : 0.000000  p now : 8

check now : 8.000000 
output[1][4] : 0.000000  
numElements in the end : 8
VMatrix parsed
```

As you can see, the strtof call succeeded (reflected in p and check variable) but not the assignment into the array.

I've only been using C for a month and I'm fascinated by it. However, it's obvious I need to learn more. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: In `make2DArray`, the line `arr[i] = temp + (i * row);` should be `arr[i] = temp + (i * col);`.

Comment: The reason why your debugging output isn't showing any assignment is because you're incrementing colArr between the assignment and trying to print out the results of the assignment.  (But this is unrelated to the root of your problem, which has already been answered.)

Comment: Hey.. ya.. just realized that :) Thanks for the comment, I didn't notice that. Placed the debug `printf`s where it should be and I can see the result now. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this

```
arr[i] = temp + (i * row);
```

should be

```
arr[i] = temp + (i * col);
```

since `i = [0,row-1]`

Comment: Thanks for catching the bug :) I've heard about C storing arrays in a row-major format.. haven't really understood it till I read it again just now.